# publish C# Excel Addin with UDF

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions, publish, excel-addins

I work on a Excel Addin in C# and my problem is present when i publish my C# Addin.

I'll explain:

I used this code: http://csharpramblings.blogspot.fr/2011/09/communicating-between-vsto-and-udfs-in.html

Which allow me to use UDF in my Addin. And it's work very well ! ... in Visual Studio 2013.

When i launch my Addin with Visual Studio i see my Addin in "COM Addins" in Excel. And my UDF in "Excel Addins" in Excel.

Then if:
 I publish my Addin with rightclick in the project in visual studio.
 I install the addin with the setup.exe generated by VS.
 I launch Excel
=> my addin works well, but my UDF doesn't work. Values of the cells are "#NAME?".

I checked in the COM Addins, my Addin is present.
I checked in the Excel Addins, i don't see my UDF.

So i used RegAsm to register the Assembly of the published DLL.
Now i see my UDF in the "Excel Addins" but it still doesn't work.

If anybody has an idea to help me that would be great !

I use: Windows 8.1 Pro, Visual Studio Pro 2013, Excel 2016 with Office365

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you register your XLAM in Office?

Comment: Your link doesnt seem to work. Getting the message ``Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. ``

Comment: I corrected the link. Sorry.

And i don't have a XLAM file. My Addin is a dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found the solution !

My mistake was to use Regasm without any parameters.
Now i use Regasm with the /codebase parameter, and i signed my assembly with a strong name. Because Regasm documentation says that:

> Creates a Codebase entry in the registry. The Codebase entry specifies
>   the file path for an assembly that is not installed in the global
>   assembly cache. You should not specify this option if you will
>   subsequently install the assembly that you are registering into the
>   global assembly cache. The assemblyFile argument that you specify with
>   the /codebase option must be a strong-named assembly.
>
> Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx

Now i see my UDF in Excel and they work.